# when tomecat server run , then my java class run

Tags: java, tomcat

I use jsf-2.x and tomcat-7.x.Now I want my server and project run same time run a java class or at first run a java class. But I do not know how to do it?

Please help me

Comment: Can you please explain better what you need? Have you tried something? Have you faced any problems? Have you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to register your class as a listener, make your class implements ServletContextListener and register it in web.xml and restart your tomcat

you can find a lot of tutorials online that shows you the details of this.

Answer (score 0):

[Startup of tomcat explanation here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/architecture/startup.html).

> The startup process can be customized in many ways, both by modifying
>   Tomcat code and by implementing your own LifecycleListeners which are
>   then registered in the server.xml configuration file.